# Trying to make my localhost wordpress installation accessible from the internet using Ngrok. Error 403

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server, localhost, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation of a website I'm developing on my mac (OSX 10.6). I can access it and make edits just fine through localhost/username/Sites/websitefolder/.

However, I need to make it accessible via the internet so I can work on it remotely and have other people look around, and I'm trying to do this by running the ngrok application (using this tutorial and the app's site itself - www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/).

I have ngrok running, but whenever I enter the address it gives me onto the browser, it returns with "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server" error.

Is there something I'm missing in order to make it accessible?

Answer (score 1):

These steps assume that all the files are in the same place as my computer in Mac OS X.

1. cd /private/etc/apache2/
2. nano httpd.conf
3. Modify the file. Follow the video steps:

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgVJnqQ_Xb8

   (I don't have time to put the video steps. I put it  later).
4. Restart the server

   sudo apachectl restart
5. Go to

   ./ngrok 80

Copy YourAdrres24dfg33.ngrok.com

6 Open httpd-vhosts.conf

cd /private/etc/apache2/extra

nano httpd-vhosts.conf

Write: ServerAlias YourAdrres24dfg33.ngrok.com under DocumentRoot

ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
    ServerAlias YourAdrres24dfg33.ngrok.com

You are set!

Comment: Can you add the steps from the video to your answer, in case the video becomes unavailable in the future?

Comment: Right now I don't have time. I will do it on Thursdays! :)